# Need help configuring Xserver for nvidia-settings (ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, nvidia, graphics, x-server

first of all I am aware that there are a lot of threads with the exact same problem online, but I was unable to resolve my issue using any of the methods I found.
I ran an nvidia bug report script to generate a report, it's on the following link: https://easyupload.io/x5snt5

I am running CudoOS (which is basically just Ubuntu for mining) with 4 GPUs (GTX1080), and I want to control fan speed manually. I am accessing the machine over SSH. Problem is that, as the title says, I can’t even open nvidia-settings without the error:
"ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system"

What I’ve tried:

1. Ran nvidia-xconfig with AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration and EnableAllGpus to generate the xorg.conf file
2. Tried setting the $DISPLAY variable to 0-4, localhost:0 and similar stuff
3. Ran nvidia-settings as “DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/var/run/lightdm/root/:0 sudo nvidia-settings”

Nothing works, I just can’t seem to get the nvidia-settings to work. I’ve also added a 10-nvidia.conf file to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d with the following content:

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option "Coolbits" "28"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/xorg"
EndSection
```

Not sure about the ModulePath attribute from above, found the xorg folder to be there. I may be missing a whole lot, but am not experienced with running nvidia hardware on Linux, so I hope someone can point me in the right direcion.

Thanks.